# Move from Basic Auth to Azure AD-OAuth2 and maintain ability to send emails for all users via SMTP on a general account

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, smtp, azure-ad-msal

I have a legacy application that uses Basic Authentication to send emails using SMTP. These emails have a general sender like "info@mycompany.com". Username and password for that account are stored by the application, so it can reuse them over and over. And other users (all same tenant btw) can use this configured setting as well.

Now I'm in the process of implementing OAuth2 with Azure AD/MSAL. I've added an App Registration that has SMTP.Send permission and I can successfully request permission and acquire a token for that in mentioned application. Now, when I send an email, the sender is me. And I really would like it to be info@mycompany.com.

What are my options? I suspect these:

1. The administrator authorizes my account to allow sending emails on behalf of mentioned general account, or
2. The administrator performs the OAuth2 configuration in my application, signing in with that general account

I guess both options require my application to store the token somehow (for which there are some nice examples, so that's not the issue). So it can be reused for other users that send emails via the application.

My question comes down to: What is the best way to approach this migration from Basic Auth to OAuth2, while maintaining the ability to send emails for all users via SMTP on one general account?